# Equivalent Resistance Calculation

Tags: resistance

[image]

Is it 5 // ((1//2) + 3)?

So the 5 is parallel with 3, which is in series with a 1 parallel with 2?

Right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is correct - the verbal description is a bit confusing.

For the Thevenin equivalent source resistance, replace the voltage source(s) with shorts and current source(s) with opens and analyze the resistance looking into the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on to what a and b are connected.  If they are left floating, then no current runs to a, which means 5 and 3 are in series, and parallel to 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2GzY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>